# Slicing Python in Reverse

Tags: python, slice, substring

In Python I know you can slice sequences as seq[from:to+1:step]. But if you slice in reverse, using a step of -1, why does it not show the from element? It shifts one element to the right from what I would expect.

```
x="012345"
x[4:2:-1]
```

prints 43, rather than 4321 as I expected. So if step is -1 then it prints seq[from:to-1:step]. Seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing goes from the first number (inclusive) to the second number (exclusive) with a step of the third number.  In your case, the first number accesses "4" and the second number accesses "2".  With a step of -1, it will start with the character at the position of the first number ("4"), and then get the next character (or with a step of -1, actually the previous character "3"), but will stop there because the second index (2) is exclusive.  To get everything from "4" to "0", you can do `x[4:0:-1]` or, more conveniently, `x[:5]`.

Comment: This makes sense, zondo. If the second number is exclusive then that explains it. So it's not really to+1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slice down to 4321 you should do `x[-2:0:-1]`.

This means to start from -2 (-1 is the last element) and go to 0 (nothing is the first element) with -1 as step.

Comment: Yep, but I kinda assumed that he wanted to go from the second last instead of from the fifth since he's stepping backwards. Perhaps that's an assumption I shouldn't make.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected.
If you need your result,

```
>>> x[4:0:-1]
'4321'
```

This means, start slicing from 5th element and go till 1st element(but not including it). This kind of slicing works only if you specify the `step size` to be negative.

So in general, follow olofom's answer.